# Issue using a custom conditional editableCellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a grid and need to implement a conditional editor template: if certain condition of the row is `true`, show a select dropdown, if not, show the regular text input. My template is this:

```
<div><form name="inputForm">
<select ng-show="row.entity.name == 'some_name'" ui-grid-edit-dropdown
        ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">
    <option value="true">true</option>
    <option value="false">false</option>
</select>
<input ng-show="row.entity.name != 'some_name'" ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
       type="text" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">
</form></div>
```

But it's not working ok...the dropdown show ok, but the text inputs don't appear when double clicking the field.

However...if I remove the `ui-grid-edit-dropdown` attribute of the `select` element, every control show ok, but now the `select` edit control doesn't disappear when I click somewhere else, as this is supposed to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by ok, nok ? can we see an example ?

Comment: As I said, in the first case, the select dropdown shows when the condition is true, but the text inputs don't. In the second case, removing the attribute, everything shows(select and text, depending the condition) but the select doesn't disappear after losing focus.

Comment: You want the dropdown menu to disappear after losing focus or conditioned to some x==y ?

Comment: I want the editor to change if the row has certain attribute, in this case, it's the field `name`. If the condition is `true`, the editor should show a dropdown select. If not, the default text input. And they should have the default behavior, that is, disappear when losing focus.

Comment: disappear when losing focus, ok, now if you want to focus on them again where would find em? i'm sorry i'm missing something.

Comment: If you want focus, double click on the cell again...that is the default behavior when using editable cells on this

Comment: if they are table cells why are they been enclosed inside `div`'s ? shouldn't they be `td` ?

Comment: No...it's not a table. In fact I've copied the default templates...